# How do I apply a CSS filter to ONLY the background image

Tags: html, css

I have a div tag with a background image that has some text text inside, I want to apply a filter to the background image without disrupting the texton the inside of the div layer. Is this possible? *(This is my first post I hope I didn't layout anything incorrectly!)*

```css
.img_container{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a1/Mallard2.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    width: 500px; 
    height: 380px; 
    filter: blur(2px);
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20%;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="img_container">
        <div class="img_text"> I want to be clear! </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the css pseudo element `::before`

```css
.img_container {
 position: relative;
 width: 500px;
 height: 380px;
 color: #333;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 20%;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.img_container::before {
 content: " ";
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a1/Mallard2.jpg");
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 filter: blur(2px);
 z-index: 0;
}

.img_text {
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_container">
  <div class="img_text"> I want to be clear! </div>
</div>
```

`::before` with the `content: " "` creates a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) before the div with class .img_text (use your browser inspect tool to see the element). This is the element we style and add a background to.

Note that you also have `::after` pseudo element to add at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Make them 2 seperate objects....

```
<div class="img_container">
</div>
<div class="img_text"> I want to be clear! </div>

.img_container{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a1/Mallard2.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    width: 500px; 
    height: 380px; 
    filter: blur(2px);
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 5;
}

.img_test {
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 380px;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 20%;
}
```

Comment: You are right but I don't really want to do that, I posted because I wanted a way around reformatting everything